# htaccess match after ~ and pass as url parameter

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server, url-rewriting

i want rewrite my url with htaccess. So, i want for example that

`https://sample.com/~X6y2`
has a match and it passes all behind the '~' as parameter to `https://sample.com/req.php?id=[here]`

is it possible with the '~'-character? so, if not, i need an alternative. Maybe '@'-Charakter, like tiktok.

So, it should match e.g.
`https://sample.com/~AZaz09,`
`https://sample.com/~0123`

but not
`https://sample.com/0123,`
`https://sample.com/AZaz09,`
`https://sample.com/XY/~Z1234,`...

I've tried several regex but nothing has provided the desired function :(

Best of these is (but not working, idk why):

`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteRule ^.*\/[\~]([a-z][^.]*)$ req.php?id=$1 [NC,L]`

I'm new to regex and htaccess, so it's a bit difficult for me. I would be grateful if someone would provide a working htaccess including regex. Thx ✌️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying, I've found a solution that is workin just fine.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*[\~]([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)$ req.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

where `~` can be replaced with anything u want :)

Answer (score 0):

You want this solution

Check this solution
Demo: https://regex101.com/r/GJPZym/1